# Numbering of cells using Python

Tags: python

I was trying the following program:

```
L = 3
r = rand(L,L)
p = 0.4
z=r<p  
imshow(z, origin='lower', interpolation='nearest', extent=[0, L, 0, L])
```

It gives me the following image

[image]

Now my questions are:

1. How can I make numbering in the cells/sites?
2. if z is true how can I make a link between them?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe this should do the trick:

```
from numpy.random import rand
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow

L = 3
r = rand(L,L)
p = 0.4
z=r<p  

f,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(z, origin='lower', interpolation='nearest', extent=[0, L, 0, L])

for i in range(z.shape[0]):
    for j in range(z.shape[1]):
        if z[i,j]:
            text = ax.text(j+0.5, i+0.5, np.round(r[i,j],3), ha="center", va="center", color="r")
```

[image]

Comment: I was going to suggest using `ax.annotate()` then I read your answer. Is there a difference between `.text` and `.annotate`?

Comment: Indeed the last line could just as easily be: annotation = ax.annotate(np.round(r[i,j],3), xy=(j+0.5, i+0.5), ha="center", va="center", color="r"). The following (and links contained) provides some good information on matplotlib text support https://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Actually I want to number the cells by 1, 2, 3....in this way.

Comment: can you please give an example/image of the exact output you want?